# Scala Pattern Match

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I am using this pattern match from regexlib.com -

```
^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-./])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$
```

This seems to be working fine =>

```
val RE = """^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-./])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$""".r
RE.findAllMatchIn("31/12/2003 11:59:59 PM").foreach(println) //prints 31/12/2003 11:59:59 PM
RE.findAllMatchIn("31/122003 11:59:59 PM").foreach(println) //prints nothing
```

However, I am not able to match it directly like this -

```
"31/12/2003 11:59:59 PM" match {
    case RE(_) => println("Yes")
    case _ => println("No")
}
```

This prints "No". I am expecting "Yes"

Comment: I think, my eyes got permanently damaged by this. How can I unsee it?
Don't do this to people, please. Just use `DateFormat`

Comment: Agreed. I am not using this in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to the capturing groups that you have several in the pattern. You need to use `RE(_*)` in the first case to just check if a string matches without extracting capturing groups:

```
val RE = """^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-./])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$""".r
    "31/12/2003 11:59:59 PM" match {
        case RE(_*) => println("Yes")
        case _ => println("No")
    }
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/6iCkch)